# when i use objecs.values('xx') i am losing my related fields

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

Firstly, sorry for couldn't find right title for my problem.

I prapered a queryset in views.py. It is grouping the countries and summing the cities population. There is no problem and i can show the sum of population and grouped country as `{% for query in queryset %}<li>{{query.countryname__name}} : {{query.country_population}}</li>{% endfor %}`

But how can i add location of country which i defined on my models.py? Or other related county fields?  Because when i use `City.objects.values('countryname__name')` i am losing my data and can not reach any field as `City.objects.all()` :(

Models.py

```
class Seasons(models.Model):
    season = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.season
    

class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    flag_def = models.CharField(max_length=50, null = True, blank = True)
    season_country = models.ManyToManyField("Seasons")
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    countryname = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    population = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    queryset = City.objects.values('countryname__name').annotate(country_population=Sum('population'))
    content = {
        "queryset" : queryset
    }
    return render(request,"index.html", content)
```

template.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Population</h1>
    {% for query in queryset %}
    <li>{{query.countryname__name}} : {{query.country_population}} {{query.countryname__name.location}} </li> 
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

display:

```
Population
Brazil : 7700000 (in here i would like to display Brazil's Season or location)
England : 3000000 (in here i would like to display England's Season or location)
Turkey : 14000000 (in here i would like to display Turkey's Season or location)
```

DataBase= https://ibb.co/bQNc6G6

Thanks Advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try:

```
from django.db.models import F

queryset = City.objects.values('countryname__name').annotate(country_population=Sum('population'), country_location=F('countryname__location'))
```

Here is [doc about F()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model)

Comment: Thank you, it is working. Now i should learn the F expressions...